# Adding and removing multiple IP address to AWS security group using Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I was trying to use Ansible to add IP addresses to an AWS security group.

I came up with a task syntax that looks like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    ip_addresses:
      - 1.2.3.4/32
      - 2.3.4.5/32
  tasks:
    - ec2_group:
        name: security-group-name
        description: Security group description
        vpc_id: vpc-1234567
        region: us-east-1
        profile: profile-name
        purge_rules: false
        rules:
         - proto: tcp
           from_port: 123
           to_port: 123
           cidr_ip: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: ip_addresses
```

This does not do exactly what I was looking for as it basically runs the `ec2_group` task multiple times instead of just looping over the rules.

This also does not work if I set the `purge_rules` to `true` as then it will purge all existing rules on each iteration, effectively removing all but the last IP address on the list.

I'm wondering if there is something similar to `with_items` that I can apply to the `rules` attribute to provide it a list of IP addresses but calling `ec2_task` only once?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve what you want with a custom filter plugin.

Create a directory in the root of your playbook called `filter_plugins` and create a file in there called `make_rules.py` with the following contents:

```
def make_rules(hosts, ports, proto):
    return [{"proto": proto,
             "from_port": port,
             "to_port": port,
             "cidr_ip": host} for host in hosts for port in map(int, ports.split(","))]

class FilterModule(object):
     def filters(self):
         return {'make_rules': make_rules}
```

Then you can do this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    ip_addresses:
      - 1.2.3.4/32
      - 2.3.4.5/32
  tasks:
    - ec2_group:
        name: security-group-name
        description: Security group description
        vpc_id: vpc-1234567
        region: us-east-1
        profile: profile-name
        purge_rules: true
        rules: {{ ip_addresses | make_rules('123', 'tcp') }}
```

Taken from: https://gist.github.com/viesti/1febe79938c09cc29501

Answer (score 3):

> This does not do exactly what I was looking for as it basically runs the ec2_group task multiple times instead of just looping over the rules.

Ansible implements loops by invoking the task once for each item in the loop, so that's expected behavior.

> I'm wondering if there is something similar to with_items that I can apply to the rules attribute to provide it a list of IP addresses but calling ec2_task only once?

Since the `rules` property for `ec2_group` actually takes a list of rules, you should be able to do the following:

```
- ec2_group:
    name: security-group-name
    description: Security group description
    vpc_id: vpc-1234567
    region: us-east-1
    profile: profile-name
    purge_rules: true
    rules:
     - proto: tcp
       from_port: 123
       to_port: 123
       cidr_ip: 1.2.3.4/32
     - proto: tcp
       from_port: 123
       to_port: 123
       cidr_ip: 2.3.4.5/32
```

Or, if you want to use pre-defined vars as in your example:

```
vars:
  my_rules:
     - proto: tcp
       from_port: 123
       to_port: 123
       cidr_ip: 1.2.3.4/32
     - proto: tcp
       from_port: 123
       to_port: 123
       cidr_ip: 2.3.4.5/32

tasks:
  - ec2_group:
      name: security-group-name
     description: Security group description
      vpc_id: vpc-1234567
      region: us-east-1
      profile: profile-name
      purge_rules: true
      rules: my_rules
```